# Can't add Repositories on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, repository

Just tried adding the 'multiverse-repo' only to get the following error:

```
sudo apt add-repository multiverse
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 19, in <module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

So I started searching about repository problems and found a solution which involved the Linux Software Manager, so I tried to open it and to my surprise it won't open!

I successfully opened Synaptic and tried to access the repository menu in an attempt to add it manually, but that menu won't open either.

I have already restarted and reinstalled certificates.

I haven't messed up any Linux files and haven't done any other changes to my PC, so I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

Your specific problem is a python error, saying that there is no python module `requests`. You can try to see if you can install the missing package `python-requests`

`apt-get install python-requests`

Sometimes you can find out if there are problems with your system state, i.e., missing packages, by running

`apt-get install -f` / `apt-get install --fix-broken`

Comment: I have already done it, it didn't worked. The problem turned out to be deeper than I thought. Posting my solution

Answer (score 0):

As I said, Software Manager was not working. Made me think A LOT of a recent installation I had done.

Tried to install Microsoft SQL-Server, which required to downgrade the OpenSSL to 1.1.0 (ridiculous as it was already in that version), all the programs that depended on OpenSSL get uninstalled as well.

That had happened four or five days ago, and 'til that moment it hadn't caused any issue, besides the fact I was off for weekend, so I didn't minded at that moment. But it did matter. A LOT.

After wasting hours checking on other forums, opened Synaptics looking for the Software Manager package name and versions and found all the Programs that got uninstalled under the Status => 'Not Installed (Residual Config)' Section.

Recovered all the programs and everything worked as usual. A reason more to install Synaptics, in case you are a novice on Linux or be a 'mess up master' like me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

"/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py" requires python3
so try:

"sudo apt install python3-requests"

It is working for me.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help with this question.  The OP posted a self answer in August describing a different problem.